# Swapping Images (Little Carousel)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem on swapping two images (from div vignette, to div gallerie).

**Situation**: I click on a little image, then It swap it place with the big image.

Here is the **HTML**

```
<div id="gallerie">
    <img id="first" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/620/350/2"><br/>
    <div id="vignette">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/100/100/6">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/100/100/4">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/100/100/3">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/100/100/2">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/100/100/1">
        <img class="second" src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/100/100/4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("vignette").addEventListener('click', changeSrc);
    function changeSrc(e) {
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName("second").src;
        var first = document.getElementById("first").src;
        s = e.target.src;
        first = s;
        console.log("click");
    }
```

For the moment, I don't want to use jQuery.

Solution on some websites use images directly on the JS code with an "if" cascade. I don't think that's efficient for me.

I can propose to use a for loop with the "var image" but I don't know how to use the e.target.

I search to perform my code, so could you explain me why I was wrong?

Here is the JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ws3f4san/

I can give you more details if you want.

Comment: You're not setting the source, you're just assigning it over the same variable `first`.

Comment: What does "Diapo" mean, and is it relevant to the question? If so, please indicate how. If not, remove from the title.

Comment: I think it means Carousel in English. There is an exemple with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block of code, you're not actually setting the source, you're just overwriting the source you've stored as a string in the `first` variable.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("second").src;
var first = document.getElementById("first").src;
s = e.target.src;
first = s;
```

`first = s;` will have no effect on the page since you're just changing a JS variable, not a dom element.

You need to edit the actual source attribute, you can do so by storing the dom element instead of the initial `src` value in the `first` variable, like so:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("second").src;
var first = document.getElementById("first"); // Store the dom element, not the string value
s = e.target.src;
first.src = s; // Now assign the new value to the src attribute of your stored dom element
```

Edited having looked more thoroughly at what you're trying to do, you can swap the src's like this:

```
function changeSrc(e) {
  // Get the initial dom element
  var mainItem = document.getElementById("first");
  // Save it's src before it's changed
  var mainItemImage = mainItem.src;
  // Get the clicked element
  var clickedItem = e.target;
  // Set the first image to the second image
  mainItem.src = clickedItem.src;
  // Set the second image to the first image's original value (which has now changed)
  clickedItem.src = mainItemImage;
}
```

Comment: I have a "GET" Error 404, but I don't understand why. The source of each image is a link to the website lorempicsum.

Comment: My bad, I made a mistake with your answer ^^' It works, thank you =)

Comment: @Arkhall I've added an alternative that will swap the images, it doesn't handle the image sizes, but you should be able to do that with CSS relatively easily (and that's a bit beyond what was asked here)